# Python - Is this a acceptable use for eval or exec? Any other way to do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, eval

I'm quite new to Python, and have been looking for a way to call a function that will have it's name formed by a conjunction of a string and a variable that is dynamically filled when the user chooses one of the options.

Example:

I start the program with a menu that gives the user certain options ( choose 1, 2, 3 or 4 )

In case user picks 1, the variable xyz will be filled with a string that is inside of a tuple or list.

Having this string assigned to the variable, I call another function that gives me another options.

If I get option 1 my code will append xyz varible to a predefined string that will form a function name ( the one which will be called next. ).

```
if int(option) == 1:
#prefixfunc will be that predefined string that will be the prefix for every function  #to be called
    exec('prefixfunc'+xyz'()')
    #or
    #eval('prefixfunc_'+xyz'()')
    #for example, we have xyz as abc, then it calls function prefixfunc_abc()
```

It works fine in the code. And I don't see it could be a liability for the case the user adds a different input. As the variable is assigned by using already defined string in a list or tuple.

I hope I've made myself clear.

Just to make clearer:

```
def maint_car():
print('It Works!!! But did you come until here in a safe way?' )

def veh_func():
func=( "Maintenance", "Prices", "Back", "Quit" )
ord = 0

for i in func:
    ord += 1
    print(ord,'\b)', i)

picked = input('\nOption: ')

if int(picked) == 1:
    exec('maint_'+xyz+'()')




def startprog():

abcd =( "car", "bike", "airplane", "Quit" )
global xyz
ord = 0
for i in abcd:
    ord += 1
    print(ord,'\b)', i)

picked = input('\nVehicle:')

if int(picked) == 1:
    xyz = abcd[0]
    veh_func()

elif int(picked) == 2:
    xyz = abcd[1]
    veh_func()

elif int(picked) == 3:
    xyz = abcd[3]
    veh_func()

elif int(picked) == 4:
    print('\nBye.\n')

startprog()
```

Comment: Please edit question and remove extra quotes or make quotes match in `'prefixfunc'+xyz'`

Comment: Do you have the ability to edit this `prefixfunc*` yourself? If so, why not make `xyz` a parameter to it?

Comment: "have been looking for a way to call a function that will have it's name formed by a conjunction of a string and a variable that is dynamically filled when the user chooses one of the options." - Why? You are looking for a way to implement a specific solution, instead of looking for a solution to a specific problem. I can't see any reason to ever do this.

Comment: What about this input: `123(); system('rm -rf .')`? Security hole.

Comment: @Linuxios Not with that specific formulation and `eval` (which expects expressions), but yeah.

Comment: @kojiro Yes I do. Can you give an example on how it should be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

For this I would use a `dict` that maps string names to functions.

```
def test():
 print "yay"

funcs = { "test": test }
funcs["test"]()
```

This provides a much better method of doing this and you can test if you want to execute the function very easily by using the `in` operator.

To answer: is your example a good use for `eval` or `exec` I would say no. If you think that `exec` is the proper answer please look at your solution and see if there is a more maintainable, simple, or explicit method to accomplish your goal. Which in this case was mapping a user input to a function to call based on certain user input.

Comment: This answer works, but I'm not so sure about it applying to the question. Mostly my doubts come from uncertainty about the question itself, but consider that there are at least three different approaches (dicts, classes, parameters), and we don't know enough to know if this answer is the best of those three. Cannot upvote.

Comment: That is a fair point, but I feel it does answer at hand because the OP wishes to map what appears to be either a string or integer to a specific function to be called. This performs this action and by doing so also removes the need for the `exec` call which is difficult to maintain and harder to read.

Comment: Sigh. I suppose I'm just feeling idealistic about the amount of principle that can be taught on SO in a single question. You're right, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do it that way, but why do it that way when there are many better ways? Such as:

```
funcs = {1: func1, 2: func2, 3: func3, 4: func4}
option = int(raw_input("Enter selection: "))
option in funcs and funcs[option]()
```

The advantage here is that you don't have to follow any particular naming convention for the functions. If option 1 is "Add a name", then you can call the function `addname()` instead of `func1()`. This will make your code much easier to follow.

Comment: Although this method decouples the text being displayed from the functions being called which makes maintenance harder (someone adds a vehicle in one place and then adds it in a different slot in the other place).

Comment: It's already decoupled. There's no relation between `prefixfunc1` and the text of menu item 1, either. You could easily put together a dict that contains the strings and the functions to call, though (or even use the function doctstrings to build the menu). I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: I will try those tips.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know the names of the methods directly, do as @kindall suggests. If you don't, you can fetch the methods for invocation using getattr(), rather than having to compile/evaluate using eval().

```
class ZZ(object):
  def fooBar(self):
    print(42)
  def barFoo(self):
    print(-42)

#now make a z
anInstance = ZZ()

#build up a dynamic string
string = 'foo' + 'Bar'

#fetch the attribute bound to string for the instance
method = getattr(anInstance, string)

#now execute the bound method/function (that's what the empty parens do)
method()

# out comes the following! Tada!
>>> 42

# we can inline a lot of this and just do things like
getattr(anInstance, 'bar' + 'Foo')()

# out comes the following! Again with the Tada...
>>> -42
```